# Unity Animator not animating player, but following transitions perfectly in Animator Window

Tags: unity, animation, animator, animation-controller

I am trying to animate a model in my project, and although I have been successful doing the same in other projects, I am not succeeding in this one.

The model does not seem to animate, although in the Animator window, everything looks fine, transitioning from one state to the other and going back.

[image: Unity issue with animation]

I have followed the tutorials to import animations from the site where I downloaded the animation, and each animation is the same as other working animations in other projects:

[image]

The animations play as expected in the inspector window.

I have tried modifying the "Apply Root Motion" in my character and it does not work either way. My Player model has these properties:

[image]

And I have tried adding a Rigid Body but it didn't work neither. I have spend several hours trying to solve this issue and I am running out of ideas to try. How can I make the animation work as expected?

Cheers!

Comment: When you crop your screenshots this tightly, you remove information we might have been able to use to help diagnose the problem. I'd recommend never cutting off the top of the inspector or object hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @DMGregory , I will keep that in mind. What information do you think would be relevant to fix this issue? If the top of the inspector could be one of the issues here, I can edit the post and add that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more hours trying to figure it out, and testing all the possible combinations, my animations play if I set the "Animation type" inside the "Rig" options of the animation, from "Humanoid" to "Generic".

It is really weird as in another project, with the same assets and configuration, it works well with the "Humanoid" option selected.

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe something was wrong with the [Avatar](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/ConfiguringtheAvatar.html)?

Comment: The avatar displays the "Avatar not in T-Pose", but in other projects, although showing that warning, the animations worked.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you import a mesh, you can import it as legacy (has their own animations baked into the mesh), or humanoid (not having any animations on their own, but having the requiered bones to pose any compatible animation).
Some designers actually provide both in the same mesh. The generic, of course, cannot use humanoid animations because it does not have the required bones to pose them. Thus, what seems to happen here is that your mesh has both...

It is always a good idea to correct the T-pose if needed, especially when humanoid animations look weird.